# iPad UIWebView with iPhone sites

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in an iPad app that should display the mobile Google. It's 320px wide like the iPhone and I have set the User Agent so that it loads mobile Google. But the web site is wider than the UIWebView although the site is optimized for mobile screens.
This is my code for creating the web view:

```
    NSDictionary *userAgentDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3", @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userAgentDictionary];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 480)];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [self addSubview:webView];
```

This is how it looks like at the moment:

[image: how it looks like now]

What can I do to make it fit? It should work with other, non-mobile pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 480)];
```

to this:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Then the WebView is resized, but I want the webview to be 320x480px, like an iPhone. However, the content does not fit while it does on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old, but for reference. You cannot set the User-Agent string of a UIWebView by default (though it would seem you can set a global persistent change via the NSUserDefaults on app launch). But let's assume you want to do this for just your google request, and not everything. Firstly, the quickest, dirtiest way to do it is [method swizzling](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/04/07/changing-the-headers-for-uiwebkit-http-requests/) a private selector. You'll then be able to set the header fields for each NSURLRequest. That's running a risk using a private API, but it does work.

The alternative, involving more work, but doesn't use any private API's would be to subclass NSURLProtocol, have it take over to the HTTP schema, and then use a 3rd party HTTP request system (e.g. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)) to manage the content retrieval. You'll have ultimate control and you can then set the custom header information onto the request without any private API usage.